# Reset NVRAM, PRAM, and SMC, all in one go from the terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, power-management, nvram, restart

I'd like to run some code, go away and have a coffee and come back to a MacBook with the [NVRAM, PRAM and SMC all reset](https://www.macworld.com/article/2881177/how-to-reset-your-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html) (rather than doing them manually with yoga postures to press all the keys, waiting around for various signals that it worked etc).

Is there a quick and easy terminal script I can run?

I have a bad mac keyboard which could 'unpress' or double press at any time so I would think the reset was performed when in fact it had not. I want to alleviate that doubt

Answer (score 2):

I'd try with a script using the following outline

```
sudo nvram -c
```

which should clear the contents of NVRAM.

```
curl 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.11.4/refind-flashdrive-0.11.4.zip/download' --output refind.usbimage
```

copy SmcFlasher there (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4855319?answerId=22024754022#22024754022)

```
shutdown -r now
```

and then you will have to manually follow the smcflasher instuctions up to

```
SmcFlasher.efi -reset 1
```

you can of course automate that as well by modifying the USB image accordingly and you'd be right where you want to be.